# validation issues in sharepoint lists

Tags: list, validation, sharepoint

I am a fresher in Sharepoint.I have set tabs using `javascript` and each tab will view the form of a list. I am keeping a `save` button for each tabs.

**The problems are :**

1. The entries are stored only when all the tabs are given inputs..i.e., all the lists are entered.
2. Totally five tabs are there. Out of them, `the tab whose fields are finally entered,alone gets saved`.Rest of the tab contents are not
   saved.

3.In addition,can we have a common save button at the end of all the tabs.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure what exatly you are trying to achieve here, the datas are not getting saved will be because of these

1. on changing the tabs, the datas may be cleared
2. Fields would be set as mandatory on the list

Please let me know

Regards
Arjun

Comment: Yes exactly,,the data are getting cleared.Can you suggest a way to overcome this issue.The scenario is :I am using 1.five tabs 2.One list within each tab 3.Common save button to all the tabs.

Comment: HI- which one are you using? Javascript or jquery??

Comment: thanks Arjun for your kind reply.The issue has been solved.The problem is when copying from two different lists,The id has to be matched in the autogenerated code of sharepoint.

Comment: okay - good to know that you have sorted the issue on your own :)